# Maven like Gradle support in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I use Eclipse and I'm switching from Maven to Gradle. The support for Maven was awesome, syntax highlighting, multiple editor tabs to add and manage dependencies, etc. However I just downloading the Gradle Buildship plugin and I find the options...non existent. Like, there's not even syntax highlighting! Is there some other plugin I should be using, or does Eclipse Gradle support just suck?

Comment: I am also finding m2eclipse's like dependency management in eclipse with gradle. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want full code completion etc for gradle scripts you could use the following `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: com.foo.MyGradlePlugin
```

Then you could create `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com/foo/MyGradlePlugin.groovy` and put all of your build logic in the plugin

```
package com.foo

import org.gradle.api.*

class MyGradlePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.with {
            apply plugin: 'java'
            dependencies {
               compile 'org.foo:bar:1.0'
            }
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

If you install the [groovy-eclipse plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/groovy-eclipse-juno) you can then have full groovy support for the groovy file including syntax highlighting and code completion (for non-dynamic code)

Another option for syntax highlighting is the [minimalist-gradle-editor](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/minimalist-gradle-editor) eclipse plugin which will highlight a `build.gradle` file but won't offer code completion

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Buildship is your best option for Gradle integration within Eclipse. Buildship currently does not provide sytnax highlighting. Adding dependencies to the build script will be reflected in the list dependencies in the IDE after triggering the "refresh dependencies" option.

Comment: Seems like Buildship became integral part of the latest Eclipse versions. Yet, it still seems lacking functionality that m2e has for Maven projects, like at least some autocomplete or navigating dependencies from the GUI...